# I/o bound processors with Round robin algorithm

Tags: process, io, scheduling

why does Round Robin algorithm doesn’t favor I/O bound processes and what changes could be made to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

An I/O bound process will use few CPU time before waiting I/O to be complete. A round robin scheduler will put it at the end of the queue even if it used a few of its quantum. A CPU bound process will use the CPU for the whole quantum it has.